# MvvmCross Tibet binding to ViewModel itself

Tags: c#, binding, mvvmcross

I have a certain use case where, for a UITableViewCell, I generate an attributed label from the whole object. Since the object is passed over as the ViewModel itself, I've used the following Fluent Binding:

```
set.Bind(this.MyLabel).For(v => v.AttributedText).To(vm => vm).WithConversion<MyLabelConverter>();
```

This resulted in the converter getting the ViewModel object itself, which has all the properties it needs, and generated the label content from there.

We're transitioning to Tibet binding, and I could not find any information about binding to the root item. Before, we had the `ViewModel` instance as `vm`, but with Tibet binding, there's no reference to it - similar to standard Microsoft XAML Binding.

With XAML Binding, however, there's a translation of `.` to the ViewModel itself. Does the same work with Tibet, or is it an unimplemented feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `.` is the way to do it.

For example (on a .axml file):

`local:MvxBind="Text MyLabel(.)"`

This binding sentence is binding the whole DataContext to the Text property / target binding, and it also uses the `MyLabelConverter` for conversion.

Comment: Yup, discovered it in the meantime. This should be included in the documentation, even if as a simple sidenote stating that binding to the whole DataContext works the same way as with Microsoft's databinding.

Comment: @fonix232 you can find it in the [docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding#swiss) under swiss binding `If $SourcePath$ is omitted or a single period "." is used, then the Source used is the whole of the ViewModel.`

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r which is relevant only to the Swiss binding format. A small extension to that sentence ("this applies to Tibet bindings too") would make it much cleaner.

Comment: @fonix232 indeed, it is not super clear in the docs but Swiss was the code name for the binding system rewrite in early 2013. Tibet then followed to extend Swiss binding syntax. So in a sense everything in Swiss is still within the Tibet binding system. With Rio and Fluent binding systems offering different approaches and syntax's.